# Precision-Recall Curve in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to visualize the Precision-Recall Curve in the Tensorflow Object Detection API?
I know that the mAP represents absolute value of the area under the curve, but i think the actual curve would be more representable for my application?
I already found some precision and recall values within the utils/metrics[1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/utils/metrics.py), but I don't know what they represent exactly, or better said, how to generate a Prec/Recall Curve out of them.
Can somebody help me, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compute_precision_recall` outputs two numpy arrays of the same length, ie. precision and recall. You can easily plot these values with matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
precision, recall = compute_precision_recall(scores, labels, num_gt)
plt.figure()
plt.step(recall, precision, where='post' )
plt.xlabel('Recall')
plt.ylabel('Precision')
plt.xlim((0, 1))
plt.ylim((0, 1))
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: According to [this blog post](https://medium.com/@timothycarlen/understanding-the-map-evaluation-metric-for-object-detection-a07fe6962cf3): "the precision-recall curve is computed from the model’s detection output, by varying the model score threshold that determines what is counted as a model-predicted positive detection of the class." Is that assertion correct, and is there a way to set the score threshold?

Comment: Noting that the `compute_precision_recall` function is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/metrics.py).

You should be able to import it like:
`from object_detection.utils.metrics import compute_precision_recall`

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` should be used instead of `import matplotlib as plt`