# Tensorflow2 Object Detection API: PR-Curve

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have trained a model using the Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API on a custom dataset with the `model_main_tf2.py` script, exported it with `export_inference_graph.py` and evaluated it with `model_main_tf2.py` by setting the checkpoint_dir flag.

I would like to see the PR-curve for my exported model. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274514/precision-recall-curve-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api) but I don't understand how this would be integrated in the TF Object Detection API.

Edit: I've run tensorboard and it shows me the standard coco-metrics (mAP, mAP@.5IOU, mAP@.75IOU.... etc). However, clicking "PR-curve" in the top right corner makes the board empty, as in seen in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You can run tensorboard. Is it not helping?

Comment: Oh, maybe I should add that in the question. I've run tensorboard and it shows me graphs for the coco metrics (mAP, mAP@.5IOU, mAP@.75IOU.... etc). However, it does not show any PR-curve :( Can I somehow enable this?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9213 found this on their github issue log.